# Всплывающее окно-календарь, PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcalendarwidget, qdatetimeedit

*Кратко:* нажимаешь кнопку - всплывает окно с выбором даты в календаре.

*Подробно:* у меня есть текстбокс и кнопка, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку 
вылазил календарь под этими элементами в виде всплывающего окна. 
А после нажатия на дату в календаре она переносится в текстбокс.

Условный пример и его код ниже:

[image: Пример]

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(47, 32, 133, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 31, 30, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(186, 31, 21, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(Dialog)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 312, 183))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Дата:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "V"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Диалоговое окно не интересует. 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Класс `QDateTimeEdit` предоставляет виджет для редактирования даты и времени.
>
> `calendarPopup : bool`
>
> Это свойство содержит текущий режим отображения всплывающего календаря. 
>   При нажатии на кнопку со стрелкой отобразится всплывающее окно с календарем. 
>   Это свойство действительно только в том случае, если существует допустимый формат отображения даты.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(47, 32, 133, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 31, 30, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(186, 31, 21, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(Dialog)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 312, 183))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Дата:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "V"))


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.dateEdit.setFont(font)
        self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)                            # +++
        self.dateEdit.setTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.LocalTime)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 31, 133, 20))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = Window() #QtWidgets.QDialog()
#    ui = Ui_Dialog()
#    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

S.Nick, спасибо!

Благодаря твоему предложению в QT Designer нашёл виджет DateEdit, где как раз-таки есть этот `calendarPopup`.

А если нужно поставить текущую дату при каждом запуске программы,то нужно прописать:

```
self.dateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
```

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(131, 42)
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Dialog)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 110, 22))
        self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: мой ответ был для вас полезным? Если вам нужно было решение для  `QT Designer`, то предоставляйте пожалуйста модуль `.ui`